# Tkinter button config method in a for loop unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple matching game using Python 2.7 and Tkinter.

The work-in-progress source code lives [here](https://github.com/arante/pyloc/blob/master/py2/htp/ex10/pairs.py).

My problem is this particular code snippet:

```
for i in range(16):
    self.img[i].config(command=lambda btn=self.btn[i]: \
            self.show_btn(self.btn[i]))
    self.btn[i].config(command=lambda btn=self.btn[i]: \
            self.hide_btn(self.btn[i]))
```

There is an existing logic error that I cannot seem to figure out.

The thing is it only configures the last two buttons that is, **img[15]** and **btn[15]**.

By the way, **img** and **btn** are two sets of Button widgets stored in a list.

Comment: You should use the lambda argument `btn` instead of `self.btn[i]` inside the lambda functions.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried `btn=btn` but then I encountered a `NameError`.  Using `btn=self.btn`, it did ran without error but then again the last 2 stacks of Button widgets only works.

Comment: Not changing the argument, but using the `btn` inside the lambda function, like `self.img[i].config(command=lambda btn=self.btn[i]: self.show_btn(btn))`.

Comment: @acw1668 it works! Thank you! So, in a lambda we are creating a variable that will be accepted as an argument of a function.